# Passing a python output value to HTML webpage

Tags: php, python, html

I am working on a audio sensor which detect the frequency or db if you called it.
Now that my python program is able to detect the 'db', but I want to use the output and sent it to my web page HTML.

I am using raspberry pi to do that, and also my web server is being hosted by the raspberry pi as well. So basically, the raspberry pi does 2 things, Host webpage & detect the frequency level.

I do not have any idea how to pass those value to HTML.

The follow code is my Python code that I got from online:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

def RCtime(Pipin):
    measurement = 0
    GPIO.setup(Pipin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(Pipin, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    GPIO.setup(Pipin, GPIO.IN)
    while(GPIO.input(Pipin) == GPIO.HIGH):
         measurement = measurement + 1
         frequency = (measurement *3.3)/1024
    return frequency

while True:
     frequency = RCtime(18)
     print 'The frequency reading is ', frequency
     time.sleep(0.2)
```

From my knowledge, I am making a guess that I maybe able to use the output value from the following statment to pass it to my HTML webpage.
`print 'The frequency reading is ', frequency`

Comment: Where is yout html-code of your webpage stored?

Comment: @Alex.S The HTML-code is actually stored in my raspberry pi "www" Apache file. And my python file is actually at the desktop.

Comment: So you can write a function that reads your html file, adds a line and then saves the file. Then you replace `print 'The frequency reading is ', frequency` with your `add_frequency_function(freq)` and that's it. You can use a text file because it is easier and every browser can open a text file. There will be no formatting though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your 'db' value into a database (sqlite for example) and then make your webpage read it.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it ? Like using PHP or something? Because my webpage is not for official use, but for my learning knowledge .